# Animations become messed up after rotating whole object. Is there an absolute (non-relative) posing mode or something?

Tags: animation, armature, transforms, keyframes

(Beginner)

I manually create keyframes with an option to include whole bone system of posed character. I wish to render animations of this character from 8 different angles, so I tried rotating it in object mode, but animations become messed when character rotation is different from original. I understand, that when I was posing bones, they must have calculated absolute viewports transform values.

Is there a way to pose armature relative to itself, so I could apply global transform to whole character and not mess up animation ? Or do I have to manipulate only camera to take all angles ?

Comment: Bones' poses *are* relative to themselves (more technically, "the transforms are in local space.")  Rotating your armature should do what you want, with typical use, and if it doesn't, it's due to something that you're not mentioning (no shame in that, you don't know what to mention yet.)  You might consider just re-orienting your camera instead of your armature as a quick workaround for your situation, but otherwise, I would need to see a file to be able to tell you what's going on.

Comment: I see. In the end my armature comes from Skin modifier, with bind to bone envelopes option selected, I didn't create armature manually.  Before I selected bone envelopes option applying skin modifier caused this armature to lose influence over mesh.  Could this be it ?

Comment: Yes, it could be related.  (Not the skin part, but envelopes, which means an unusual way of interacting with your armature.)  Make sure that your armature is the parent of your mesh object.

Comment: Oh right, thanks a lot, I wish there was a way to vote on a comment :)

Answer (score 0):

Generally when you parent the mesh to the armature using Ctrl P the mesh object becomes child of the armature object (and vertex groups get relations with bones), so keyframing the whole armature in object mode should do what you're looking for.